# How to set email and data configuration in activiti-explorer-5.22

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I just changed in activiti-custom-context.xml file and after changes also i am not able to send the email to the users  and  i have changed the database properties also but after relaunch server ,my server is not connected to the database ,which I provided.

```
<class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/explorer" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="passw`enter code here`ord" value="root" />
    </bean> --> 

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    </property>
    <property name="mailServerUseTLS" value="true" /><!--This is important if you use Gmail as your hoster -->
    <property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="mailServerPort" value="587" />
    <property name="mailServerUsername" value="my@host.com" />
    <property name="mailServerPassword" value="hostpassword"/>
       </bean>

    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="formService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getFormService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />
    <bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getIdentityService" />  

</beans>
```

Comment: Just to understand : is it activiti in alfresco or the standalone activiti product ? What is the problem ? Do you have some logs to provide us ?

Comment: Its alfresco-activiti engine(activiti-explorer-5.22)

Comment: Ok, what about my two other questions ?